# Error 128 (0x80) while trying to subscribe to topic with paho-mqtt

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

I'm using [hbmqtt 0.9.6](https://github.com/beerfactory/hbmqtt) as a broker and [paho-mqtt 1.5.1](https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/) as a client. Both of them support [MQTT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MQTT) v3.1.1.

Broker configuration:

```
listeners:
    default:
        type: tcp
    halp:
        max-connections: 33
        bind: 127.0.0.3:1883
topic-check:
    enabled: false
auth:
    allow-anonymous: true
```

Client code:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code " + str(rc))
    client.subscribe('abc')

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.topic + " " + str(msg.payload))

def on_subscribe(mosq, obj, mid, qos):
    print("Subscribed: " + str(mid))
    print("Granted QoS: " + str(qos[0]))

client = mqtt.Client(client_id="subscriber", transport="tcp")

client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.on_subscribe = on_subscribe

client.connect("127.0.0.3", 1883)

client.loop_forever()
```

The client establishes a connection to the broker correctly and can send messages to the broker without any problems. But when I try to subscribe to a topic, I receive `Granted QoS: 128`. What can cause that kind of problem?

**What I've tried**:

1. Change topic name
2. Change IP address and port
3. Change transport from TCP to ws
4. Change OS (tried on Armbian and [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29))
5. Use authentication with login:password

Comment: SUBACK(128) usually means that your client does not have the necessary permissions for the desired subscription.

Comment: I think that if that was the case, then login/password should've helped

Comment: What is "ws"? [web service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service#W3C_Web_services) (W3C)?  [SOAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) over HTTP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fraschbi was](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66712759/error-128-0x80-while-trying-to-subscribe-to-topic-with-paho-mqtt/67146054#comment117929312_66712759) right. The problem was with the specified version of hbmqtt: it ignored permission configurations. A workaround is to specify what topics the client can subscribe to.